# Simple Injector registering dynamic types

Tags: c#, .net, repository, simple-injector

Hi I want to automate little bit registration of my dependencies.

What i have now is:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class

public interface IFolderRepository : IRepository<Folder>

public class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepository<T>, IDisposable where T : class

public class FolderRepository : RepositoryBase<Folder>, IFolderRepository
```

I have registered this dependency:

```
 container.Register<IFolderRepository, FolderRepository>();
```

All work fine but in one place i need to make this process generic. Like:

```
var repository = container.GetInstance<IRepository<TModel>>();
```

and I had to register:

```
container.Register<IRepository<Folder>, RepositoryBase<Folder>>();
```

Is there any way to nicely register IRepository to return for me for example FolderRepository if T : Folder.

Thanks

Comment: Why have IFolderRepository in the first place? If you already have IRepository<Folder> and you're trying to get an instance of `IRepository<Folder>`?

Comment: What exactly is the function of this specific `IFolderRepository` interface? If your intention is to add specific methods, [please don't](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register all generic instances  using `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric`:

```
container.RegisterManyForOpenGeneric(typeof(IRepository<>),
    typeof(IRepository<>).Assembly);
```

and for open types:

```
container.RegisterOpenGeneric(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(RepositoryBase<>));
```

See documentation [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced.html#registration-of-open-generic-types)

Comment: And the nice thing about `RegisterOpenGeneric` is that it uses unregistered type resolution, which basically means that it works as a fallback mechanism in case no explicit registration is made for a closed version of the interface using `RegisterManyForOpenGeneric`.